# Сахар свекольный или свекловичный?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Встретил в тексте определение "свекловичный сахар". Насколько это правильно? Мы говорим, например, "свекольный суп", но почему тогда сахар свекловичный? Или это какой-то профессиональный термин?
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ на Ваш вопрос можно найти в словаре:

СВЁКЛА, -ы,  ж. Корнеплод  с  толстым  сладким корнем,  идущим  в пищу. Столовая с. (с красным корнем). Кормовая с. Сахарная с. || прил. свекольный,

СВЕКЛОВИЦА, -ы, ж. Сахарная свекла. || прил. свекловичный. С. сахар.

Comment: Не исключено, что свёкла отличается от свекловицы также, как дырка отличается от отверстия.

Comment: А как же столь часто встречаемый термин "сахарная свекла"?

Comment: И  тот  и  другой  равноупотребляемы ( свекловица  или  сахарная  свекла ).